# LimitIterator and DirectoryIterator way of working

Tags: php, file, iterator, directory

If I have a directory with 600 files in it.
Now I try to get the 300 to 350 files.
I will use a Limit Iterator with Directory Iterator.
How does it work in the backend, Does it do a full directory scan, or does it some how know to jump directly to file 300 in the dir?

[DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)
[LimitIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just have a try ...

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('your/path/here/');
$iterator = new LimitIterator($dir, 300, 50);

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

This code is untesteted. The foreach loop just works like if you iterate with the DirectoryIterator itself.

Comment: This will "grant" me access to only the 300 to 350 files in the directory, granted. but, my question is, did it went through all the other files before that in the process.

Comment: No. It 's one of the advantages of the Iterator object of the SPL. It just holds the items in memory, which are really in need.